# Changing cell size output for Proximity (Raster Distance) tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity, resolution

I am trying to create a raster layer with distance to shore that has a resolution of 1km.

I've created a raster distance layer using the Raster > Analysis > Proximity (Raster Distance) tool in QGIS which worked however the difference between each section is 15km. I need the cell size to be more accurate as I will be using it in a species distribution model.

Is there any way to do this on QGIS?

Comment: What is the pixel size of your source raster?

Comment: The input file is 0.009 map units per pixel so approx 1 km

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the Proximity analysis will use the grid resolution provided

If accuracy is paramount then first I would project the raster into an equidistant CRS and then resample to 1km grid resolution. GDAL Warp in QGIS allows you to specify the new CRS and the new output resolution. 
This is particularly important if your study area is at a continental or sub-continental scale. 0.009 degrees may approximate to 1km but can vary with changing latitude and longitudes.

Then run your Proximity analysis on this projected data and you should get the results you are after. You would also need to project and resample all other predictors in your SDM